# Is it possible to detect if a web page is shown inside an Infragistics igDialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infragistics, ignite-ui

My web page is shown sometimes without container and sometimes inside an igDialog of another container page, depending on the navigation of the user inside our web application.

Is it possible (in pure javascript or jQuery) to detect from my page if I am inside an igDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may not meet your *"pure JavaScript"* requirement, but here is how I would do it.

Add a parameter to query string when accessing the page, such as `"mywebpage?igdialog=true"`
Then you could use JavaScript to check if that parameter is set.